# Spring boot jdbc session only for logged-in users

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Session JDBC in my spring boot application and it's working fine. But it's resulting into lot of calls to database. I want to only invoke the jdbc session management for authenticated users and the anonymous users can keep using the default spring session management. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No. Spring Session is a replacement for the regular http session. So you either use it or you don't, there is no middle ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [doc](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session), Spring Session is a replacement of the regular HTTP session, therefore you cannot have both of them.

Usually, the performance overhead in the case you report should be minimal, or handled by database caches in a way to be neglectable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so neglectable on ddos/penetration testing even you bruteforce the main domain of the app, with a postgres database behind has the side effect to fill the pg_wal and crash the database.